# how to remove line break in between column of csv file

Tags: csv, file, unix

below is the csv file which has line break in between one row

"-658924041","08/06/2020 11:46:06","kjljjlkjjl","3","EF1B09C","DD3582AF"
"-658924042","08/06/2020 11:46:06","kjljjlkjjl","3","EF1B09C
","DD3582AF"
"-658924043","08/06/2020 11:46:06","kjljjlkjjl","3","EF1B09C","DD3582AF"
"-658924044","08/06/2020 11:46:06","kjljjlkjjl","3","EF1B09C","DD3582AF"

second row got line break , but need the output as below

"-658924041","08/06/2020 11:46:06","kjljjlkjjl","3","EF1B09a","DD3582AF"
"-658924042","08/06/2020 11:46:06","kjljjlkjjl","3","EF1B09b","DD3582AF"
"-658924043","08/06/2020 11:46:06","kjljjlkjjl","3","EF1B09C","DD3582AF"
"-658924044","08/06/2020 11:46:06","kjljjlkjjl","3","EF1B09d","DD3582AF"

Comment: with which language / softare / tool / library are you tring to parse it. because the newline is in double quotes ("") which most csv libraries can deal with, (usually it is called text delimiter)

Comment: I am trying to load this file using oracle external table(slqloader) , it has CRLF, using Unix,  in window its handle like ,fileText.Replace("\r\n", "").Split('\n');)

Comment: used sed -e "s/\r//g" <file_name> but no luck

Comment: I've tired in windows fileText.Replace but DOS nor Powershell finds it a valid command. in which language are you trying to do this, and on wich unix platform are you, what shells have you available?

Comment: its /bin/bash
and x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: i have used sed command as below sed -e "s/\r//g" but its not replacing the line break, its comma-delimited file with field enclosed in double quotes

Answer (score 0):

> i have used sed command as below sed -e "s/\r//g" but its not replacing the line break

The *line break* character would be `\n`, but the pattern space does not contain that in the first place.

What we can do is, for lines not ending with `"` (and perhaps spaces as in your example), let `sed` append the next line to the pattern space and then remove the embedded newline:

```
sed '/" *$/b;N;s/\n//' file_name
```